# HTML form autocomplete address semantics

Tags: html, autofill, vcf-vcard, hcard

I am working on a registration form that requires home and work addresses upon submitting.
The fields are as follows:

```
<html>
  <form>
    <input name="street-address" autocomplete="home street-address" required />
    <input name="postal-code" autocomplete="home postal-code" required />
    <input name="locality" autocomplete="home locality" required /> <!-- or "home city" -->

    <input name="organization" autocomplete="organization" required />
    <!-- addressee or department withing the organization. optional field -->
    <input name="addressee" autocomplete="????????" />
    <input name="work-street-address" autocomplete="work street-address" required />
    <input name="work-postal-code" autocomplete="work postal-code" required />
    <input name="work-locality" autocomplete="work locality" required />
  </form>
</html>
```

I am using http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard and https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-fe-autocomplete-organization-title to create a nice browser compatible autofill form.

What I can't figure out is if there is a nice autofill name for the addressee / department field. 
Is anyone familiar with this / or any input?

Answer (score 7):

I assume you want to use full `street-address`. if you just want to use address line 1 then try `address-line1`.

See [MDN Specification here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autocomplete)

Also [Google Developers page](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill#address) (Note: in this example you could see `locality, ...` but they are deprecated. use )